# How to find value of unknown resistance when only net voltage and current across unknown resistor is given (in parallel)

Tags: resistance

[image]
I have just started learning thus as it was not my core subject. I searched on google and tried to search for a relevant youtube video. But I was not able to find a proper answer.

Comment: Do you know that the voltage across the parallel circuit is the same?

Comment: @G36 i know that but how to find that here

Comment: @user287001 i have edited the question and deleted the unnecessary part

Comment: 10V = (I1 + 2A)*10Ohm + I1*10ohms solve for I1

Comment: So how do we got 10 v and across which resistor

Comment: Good catch. I do the KVL around the loop. Vbat = 100V; so 
 
100V = (I1 + 2A)*10Ohm + I1*10ohms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually some quidance is already given. Here's another: Assume unknown U from node B to F. At node B you can write Kirchoff's current law equation (100V -U)/10Ohm = U/10Ohm+2A. Then calculate your R from Ohm's law.